# Copy comma separated values to another sheet in separate columns automatically in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a way to track attendance. I have a template setup with spaces for employee names, points, etc.

I have a comma separated list of employee names. I have the script adding a new sheet per name and renaming the sheet with the employee name. What I need is the name to be separated to specific cells on the new sheet created by the template automatically.

Sheet 1, Name List:

[image: Comma separated List]

Sheet 2 thru infinite:

[image: New sheet created from template]

This probably requires a separate question, but I need to be able to add names to the list so it can create new tabs without making duplicates.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into `Split()`

Comment: Have you considered using `Text to Columns` in the `Data` menu? You could use `,` as the delimiter. If so, you could record a macro and then you have your VBA code ready and done.

Comment: @Ralph When I try 'Text to Columns' having it separate it onto another sheet, I get a bad reference error.

Comment: You can only use `Text to Columns` on the same sheet and then move the data to another sheet. As I said: do it manually and record your doings at the same time and Excel / VBA will write the code for you. Give it a try.

Comment: @Ralph Thanks. I have the code now, however, I need this to happen automatically for each name and any new names added to the list in the future. Any ideas?